# Hide controls in multiple User Controls using their label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have multiple User Controls each containing a number of controls. I would like to hide these according to a label (or multiple labels) in code-behind only, without having to (or at least minimally) touch my XAML.

This "hiding of controls" needs to happen automatically whenever a User Control is opened as well.

How could this be efficiently done?

Comment: I guess you should provide more details and - above all - you should show some code

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the most efficient way would be to control the visibility with setters in the XAML. If it has to be via code-behind, I don't think it is going to be very efficient (in terms of lines of code), but you could do it easily with events and accessing the controls visibility state by ControlName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed.

Comment: To get best advice that suite for you, you should post your code here.